# Can you create custom place types to return in Google Place Autocomplete?

Tags: java, android, autocomplete

I'm using Google Places Api on Android. I need to restrict my search results to football/soccer fields, but there doesn't seem to be a way to restrict results to this type of place.

Here's the Google's documentation: https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/supported_types

So is there a way to create a custom filter for  Autocomplete search results? If there is no way to do it with Google's Autocomplete, are there any other possibilities to filter search results to football/soccer fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `Filterable` to filter result.I am not familiar with the API but this might help.change to what satisfies your needs.

```
class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter implements Filterable {

private List<Data> dataList;
private List<Data> mSdataFilterList;
        public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
            super(context, resource);
           //initialize both lists with unfiltered data
        }

        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            // return a filter that filters data based on a constraint

            return new Filter() {
                @Override
                protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                for (int i = 0; i < mSdataFilterList.size(); i++) {
                if ((mSdataFilterList.get(i).getData().toUpperCase())
                        .contains("footbal")||(mSdataFilterList.get(i).getData().toUpperCase())
                        .contains("soccer")) {

                    Data data= new Data(
                    mSdataFilterList.add(data);
                }
            }
            results.count = mSdataFilterList.size();
            results.values = mSdataFilterList;
                    return results;
                }

                @Override
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                  dataList= (ArrayList<Data>) results.values;
                  notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            };
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own repository in firebase of filtered/confirmed soccer fields and then use this list as the source for your autocomplete view.